# Animating gradient fill in swiftUI

Tags: swiftui

Having rectangle with gradient fill and trying to animate color change.

```
...
  Rectangle()
    .fill(LinearGradient(
          gradient: .init(stops: [Gradient.Stop(color: myColor, location: 0.0), Gradient.Stop(color: .blue, location: 1.0)]),
          startPoint: .init(x: 0.5, y: startPoint),
          endPoint: .init(x: 0.5, y: 1-startPoint)
          ))
     .animation(Animation.easeIn(duration: 2))
...
```

While change of starting points is animated nicely; the color change is not animated at all and just "switches"

Any hints?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So if anyone will be struggling with that my current solution is **having two gradients in ZStack and animating opacity of the top one**

[Example gif](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q35FN.gif)

*Here is rough example, the code sure can be written more nicely:*

```
///helper extension to get some random Color
extension Color {
  static func random()->Color {
    let r = Double.random(in: 0 ... 1)
    let g = Double.random(in: 0 ... 1)
    let b = Double.random(in: 0 ... 1)
    return Color(red: r, green: g, blue: b)
  }
}

struct AnimatableGradientView: View {
  @State private var gradientA: [Color] = [.white, .red]
  @State private var gradientB: [Color] = [.white, .blue]

  @State private var firstPlane: Bool = true

  func setGradient(gradient: [Color]) {
    if firstPlane {
        gradientB = gradient
    }
    else {
        gradientA = gradient
    }
    firstPlane = !firstPlane
  }

  var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        Rectangle()
            .fill(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: self.gradientA), startPoint: UnitPoint(x: 0, y: 0), endPoint: UnitPoint(x: 1, y: 1)))
        Rectangle()
            .fill(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: self.gradientB), startPoint: UnitPoint(x: 0, y: 0), endPoint: UnitPoint(x: 1, y: 1)))
            .opacity(self.firstPlane ? 0 : 1)
        ///this button just demonstrates the solution
        Button(action:{
            withAnimation(.spring()) {
                self.setGradient(gradient: [Color.random(), Color.random()])
            }
        })
        {
            Text("Change gradient")
        }
    }
  }
}
```

**Update**: *In the end I have explored several ways of  animating gradient fills and summarized them here: https://izakpavel.github.io/development/2019/09/30/animating-gradients-swiftui.html *

Comment: What if I just want to animate it between gradientB & gradientA ?

Answer (score 3):

Wanted to share one more simple option.

**Two rectangles with animated solid colors on top of each other.
The top ZStack uses a gradient mask to blend them together.**

```
    struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var switchColor = false
   
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30)
                .fill(switchColor ? Color.purple : Color.green)
            ZStack {
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30)
                    .fill(switchColor ? Color.pink : Color.yellow)
            }
            .mask(LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.clear,.black]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom))
            
        }
        .padding()
        .onTapGesture {
            withAnimation(.spring()) {
                switchColor.toggle()
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```